# MediaElement in Windows UWP app not playing audio

Tags: c#, windows, audio, uwp, media

```
        MediaElement player = new MediaElement();
        player.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Media/backgroundtrack.mp3");
        player.Volume = 100;
        player.Play();
```

What is wrong with this code? When I run my program, there is no sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("ms-appx:///Assets/Media");
if(folder != null)
{
    var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("backgroundtrack.mp3");
    if(file != null)
    {
        var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
        mediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
        player.Volume = 100;
        player.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, do you have any idea why both solutions (one in the question and the other in your answer) are not working?

Comment: Hi there. What exactly is not working? Are you able to open the file properly? Is it in supported format? Is there a problem with the sound only or the video image playback too?

Comment: The MediaElement is not playing. But never mind, I have found the solution. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'm trying to play an mp3 file with the code from this answer (UWP App on Windows mobile 10 device), everything works, the stream has a length that fits the file, there are no exceptions, but the MediaElement just doesn't play. I tried to output the MediaElements position, it stays on 00:00, so it shouldn't be an volume/mute issue. Does anybody have an idea? @Sneaky Lone maybe? What else can I try to debug this?